# Comment exprimer différemment ou non le « shoo-in » selon différents paramètres de la phrase ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

[*Larousse en ligne bilingue*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/shoo-in/611372) nous dit au sujet de la traduction de *shoo-in* (« a candidate or contestant generally agreed upon as the presumptive winner; somebody who is well-liked or widely agreed upon », *Wiktionary*), qu'avec la locution *he's/she's a shoo-in* on pourrait avoir « il/elle gagnera à coup sûr » alors qu'avec l'inanimé on aurait « c'est couru d'avance ». Je suis tombé sur un ensemble de phrases contenant l'expression ([Wik.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shoo-in#English), [Camb.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shoo-in) ; voir aussi [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141222/shoo-in-vs-shoe-in-and-etymology)), parfois avec des verbes un peu différents de l'auxiliaire *être* uniquement ou suivie de la préposition *for* etc., et sur un exemple de traduction (*A History of Violence*, Cronenberg, 2005) :

> She's very popular and good with numbers, so I expect she'll be a
> **shoo-in** for treasurer.
>  Participation in primaries was often more
> important than in the general election because the Democratic Party
> nominee was a **shoo-in for** success in the general election.
>  Tannery
> was considered **something of a shoo-in**; he even began writing his
> inaugural lecture.
>  Darryl thinks his popularity with the staff
> **will make him a shoo-in**, so he thinks he doesn't have to do an
> interview like everyone else. 
>  Before you pulled that shit with
> Fogarty... I was a **shoo-in to take over** when the boss croaked. / Avant
> tes conneries avec Fogarty, j'étais **à deux doigts de reprendre la
> boutique** quand le boss est mort.

Comment s'attaque-t-on aux défis de traduction de cette expression quand on sort un peu de la formulation telle que présentée chez *Larousse* : comment va-t-on par exemple intégrer le « degré quelconque » (*something of a shoo-in*) ; s'agit-il simplement d'appliquer la solution présentée au Larousse, va-t-on utiliser « une personne pour qui c'était gagné d'avance » ou reformuler en amont et comment par exemple ; pourquoi la solution de la dernière phrase est-elle satisfaisante ou non ? (On peut choisir parmi les exemples de phrases qui précèdent ou d'autres pour illustrer.).

Comment: "le favori"....

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker Le _favori_ est utile mais si on l'essaye dans la première phrase, ça semble incomplet (_donc je m'attends à ce qu'elle soit la favorite pour le poste de trésorier_), alors qu'avec la dernière phrase ça semble imprécis ou pas assez intense (la favori pour reprendre la boutique) ? Avec le favori + _for success_ il faut certainement remanier. Ce sont surtout ces détails qui m'intéressent, et quand on choisirait plutôt de remanier pour se rapprocher de _il gagnera à coup sûr_.

Comment: Dans ce cas, si c'est vraiment l'idée de gagner presqu'à coup sûr, il est courant d'adjoindre l'adjectif "grand", par ex. comme ceci "il est le **grand favori** dans la compétition". Autre tounure :  "elle a **toutes les chances** d'emporter la décision". Par contre, on ne dirait guère "je m'attends à ce qu'elle soit la favorite" ou alors "je m'attends à ce qu'elle l'emporte"